# 'init(_:isActive:destination:)' was deprecated in iOS 16.0: use NavigationLink(_:value:) inside a NavigationStack or NavigationSplitView

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, mobile

I have tried to build an app by LBTA, and the author is using this method of NavigationLink:

```
var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack{
                
                customNavBar
                messagesView
                
                NavigationLink("", isActive: $shouldNavigateToChatLogView){
                    Text("Chat Log View")
                }
                
            }
            .overlay(newMessageButton, alignment: .bottom)
            
        }.navigationBarHidden(true)
            
        
    }
```

but this method is deprecated in IOS 16, which I use and I am trying to make it by new method
`NavigationLink(_:value:)`, but I dont understand how to do it correctly to code work.
This is how I have tried to do this:

```
 var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack{
                
                customNavBar
                messagesView
                
                NavigationLink(value: shouldNavigateToChatLogView){
                    Text("Chat Log View")
                }
                
            }
            .overlay(newMessageButton, alignment: .bottom)
            
        }.navigationBarHidden(true)
            
        
    }
```

Code has compiled, but NavigationLink hasn't worked anymore.

I used to search this in Apple's SwuftUI migration website, and in stackowerflow also, but I just don't undersand how it works. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `.navigationDestination`:

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationStack {
        VStack{
            
            customNavBar
            messagesView
            
            NavigationLink(value: shouldNavigateToChatLogView){
                Text("Chat Log View")
            }
            .navigationDestination(for: ChatLog.self) { log in
                ChatLogView(log: log)
            }
        }
        .overlay(newMessageButton, alignment: .bottom)
        
    }.navigationBarHidden(true)
}
```

Assuming you have a `ChatLogView` that takes a `ChatLog`.